# How to get the exact match or sub string of the passed query in solr

Tags: solr, content-search

I'd like to query a string to `Solr` and let it answer with all records which are a subset of that string.

The string is separated by a comma. I wanna make Solr to give me all records where a specific string field is a subset of the string provided as the request.

**Example**

Imagine I have a string field indexed in Solr which is a set of strings separated by a comma. For example, let's say I have the following record's field indexed in Solr:

```
"AAA, AAB"

"AAA"

"AAA, AAB, AAC"

"AAA, AAB, AAC, AAD"

"AAA,AAC,AAD"

"AAA,AAD"

"AAD"

"AAB,AAC"
```

I wanna Solr to receive a query with, for example, "AAA, AAD" and reply with the following records:

```
"AAA"

"AAA ,AAD"

"AAD"
```

If I query by "AAA, AAB, AAC" the retrieved records would be...

```
"AAA"

"AAA,AAB"

"AAA ,AAB, AAC"

"AAB ,AAC"
```

The retrieved records must be exactly a subset of the string provided

Is it possible to make `Solr` behave like this?

Comment: Hi Meenu, in this scenario, you can get query in your search function and create a list split with a comma and then apply a foreach loop on this list, then in this loop you can check contains to this solr index field.

Comment: Gaurav, I am looking for a solr query to do this all and give the final records .

Comment: yes Meenu, I am telling the same..suppose your method 
public abc xyx(string query){
// create a list by slpit comma
//create a solr query here
foreach(var a in list){
// add your logic here against solr query
query = query.Where(i=>i.solrField.contains(a));
}
}

Comment: or you can create predicate as well

Comment: Meenu check this - https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/18362/searching-a-substring-using-solr

Comment: I do not  have access to change the code in solr but i can change the schema . i am just forming the query in my backed and passing it to solr server i.e  fq = Name :"AAA,AAB" ,and expecting subset of the query AAA,AAB   or AAA or AAB only     Schema.xml :  <field name="Name" type="commaDelimited" indexed="true" stored="true"/>